# Xml file not opening

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am developing C# application, but I encountered a problem while typing into xml file. Let me show the code first:

```
Company comp = new Company();
comp.CompanyID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
comp.CompanyName = comboBox1.Text;
comp.Serial = strEncryptedData;
comp.ListProduct = ll;

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Company));
    serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, comp);
    xDoc.LoadXml(stringWriter.ToString());
}
string temp = xDoc.OuterXml;
MessageBox.Show(temp);
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\test.xml");
sw.WriteLine(temp);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

Program writes the file but when i try to open it in xml format, i recieve blank document, nothing inside. When i opened it in text editor i recieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><CompanyXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><CompanyName /><CompanyID>100</CompanyID><Serial>00000G2SB4BER9PSFJİ2GTVM2UC1VYEİ</Serial></CompanyXml>
```

It is the correct data I receive, but however cannot be opened as xml.

How can I format it? Or am I doing something wrong while writing it?

Comment: "it cannot be opened" isn't nearly enough information. What are you trying to use to read it? What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. When i clicked on that file (test.xml), it opens an blank document. Nothing inside.

Comment: Please provide the deserializer code, too. I guess this is where you encounter the error.

Comment: We still don't know what program you're using to open the file. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: The output XML looks correct to me. Is it because you want the elements on separate lines and indented?

Comment: @JonSkeet Office xml handler

Comment: @RomanoZumbé What makes you say that? It looks like he's serialization the `comp` object which is then later loaded into the doc

Comment: @Alasse: Well it's not at all clear that you can expect the results of C# XML serialization to open pleasantly in Office...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove this text **encoding="utf-16"**  from your first line of xml then you will open the xml.

Comment: @Alasse, if an answer was helpful to you, please mark it as "answered" so other people with the same issue can see how it was fixed for you.

Comment: @LarsKristensen i know man, it was giving an error when i tried to mark, like minimum time to choose answer did not pass or something like that.

Comment: @Alasse, Alright - I didn't check your profile, but people with low reputation tend to forget it. Now that I've checked, I see you mark nearly every question you've asked! That's awesome!! :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be with the encoding, removing `utf-16` or changing to `utf-8` corrects it.

You could try the [StreamWriter constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aadshsx.aspx) which takes an encoding to see if it saves the .xml with the correct encoding.

For example:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

However, i found some other way to solve this issue after you guys pointed out utf format issue.

First of all we create a class which extends to StringWriter

```
public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

Then we edit code into this by modifying **StringWriter**:

```
Company comp = new Company();
comp.CompanyID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
comp.CompanyName = comboBox1.Text;
comp.Serial = strEncryptedData;
comp.ListProduct = ll;

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new Utf8StringWriter())
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Company));
    serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, comp);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\text.xml");
    sw.WriteLine(stringWriter);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}
```

Regards...